# Solving this three variable diophantine equation.

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

What technique(s) can be employed to solve this equation for integers? My target is non-zero integer solutions. I don't have a clue on how to solve this purely by hand. :

$z^2 = (y^3 - 51)^2 - 12k \cdot (6y^2 - \sqrt{36y^4 - 48y(y^3 - 51) + 576k} )$

This equation is a merger of two equations:

$12x^2 - 6y^2 \cdot x + y(y^3 - 51) - 12k = 0$

and

$z^2 = (y^3 - 51)^2 - 288k \cdot x$

For the first quadratic equation, it's easy to make $k$ the subject of the equation and substitute values into $y$ and work out for $x$ but the results therefrom doesn't fit into the second equation. So I expressed $x$ in terms of the quadratic formula and put into the second equation that's why the initial equation appears monstrous.
I'd appreciate it if anyone can find solutions that satisfy both equations.

Thanks!

Comment: Context might help...this seems very arbitrary, is there anything behind the problem?  In particular, is there any reason to expect a sensible answer?  After all, this is at least a $6^{th}$ degree equation, $12^{th}$ degree once you clear the square root, and such things are typically hard to address.  And what have you tried?  Have you done a basic search?

Comment: It has obvious solutions for $y=0$, to start with. Note that $576=24^2$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yeah. I'm aware of solutions for (x,y,z) = (2635992751,465,4544838) but I do not know which approach to use systematically to arrive at the solutions, that's why I was asking. Either computer codes or any known method.

Comment: is your equation related to your [previous one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4807667/solving-a-trivariate-diophantine-equation-of-a-quadratic-form?noredirect=1)?

Comment: What makes you think that such "monster" equations can be solved by hand ? As the given solution shows , it is even an enormous task to find the solutions with electronic help.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yeah. y is equal to 6x + 3.

Comment: @Peter this equation is a merger of two separate equations:  I'll edit it into the main question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resultant $Res_x\bigg(12 x^2 - 6 y^2 x + y (y^3 - 51) - 12 k, -z^2 + (y^3 - 51)^2 - 288 k x\bigg)\\=(z^2 + 72 k y^2 - (-51 + y^3)^2)^2 - 1728 k^2 (48 k + 204 y - y^4)\\ 
\implies 3(48 k + 204 y - y^4)=\square$

Let $3(48 k + 204 y - y^4)=w^2$.

$Res_k\bigg(\bigg\{12 x^2 - 6 y^2 x + y (y^3 - 51) - 12 k, -z^2 + (y^3 - 51)^2 - 288 k x\bigg\}, 3 (48 k + 204 y - y^4) - w^2\bigg)\\=\bigg\{(w + 12 x - 3 y^2) (w - 12 x + 3 y^2), (-2601 + 2 w^2 x - 1224 x y + 102 y^3 + 6 x y^4 - y^6 + z^2)\bigg\}$

$Res_x\bigg((-2601 + 2 w^2 x - 1224 x y + 102 y^3 + 6 x y^4 - y^6 + z^2), (w + 12 x - 3 y^2)\bigg)\\=(15606 + w^3 - 612 w y - 3 w^2 y^2 + 1224 y^3 + 3 w y^4 - 3 y^6 - 6 z^2)$

Let $y$ parameter, then get elliptic equation over $w,z\in\mathbb{Z}$:

$w^3 - w^2 3 y^2 + w 3 y (-204 + y^3) - 3 y^3 (-408 + y^3) + 15606 = 6 z^2$

Solving in [pari/gp](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/gp.html):

```
{
 for(y=-1000, 1000,
  H= hyperellratpoints((15606+'w^3-612*'w*y-3*'w^2*y^2+1224*y^3+3*'w*y^4-3*y^6)/6, 10^7);
  for(i=1, #H,
   z= H[i][2];
   if(z>0, if(z==floor(z),
    w= H[i][1];
    k= (w^2-612*y+3*y^4)/144;
    if(k==floor(k),
     x= (3*y^2-w)/12;
     if(x==floor(x),
      if(x!=0, if(12*x^2-6*y^2*x+y*(y^3-51)-12*k==0 && -z^2+(y^3-51)^2-288*k*x==0,
       print("("x", "y", "z", "k")")
      ))
     )
    )
   ))
  )
 )
}
```

Output `(x,y,z,k)` for $|y|<1000$:

```
(-488917, -984, 8882365635, 553864886575)
(-86359, -939, 1851808374, 110316146278)
(-358020, -489, 4258525020, 175748277075)
(4380, -309, 12316560, 569800770)
(-10104, -309, 69151776, 1344180588)
(4344, -285, 6720168, 392242566)
(-127896, -285, 902562072, 22101356046)
(-12015, -99, 27053970, 211245120)
(-28, -21, 16560, 23254)
(-2716, -21, 2500272, 7991830)
(-1071, 0, 594813, 1147041)
(-1560, 51, 1508520, 5025930)
(-247, 69, 537030, 2537626)
(-6783, 264, 40999395, 687176319)
(11424, 459, 26676672, 2625969600)
(13289, 465, 4544838, 2635992751)
(-122317, 465, 1067827410, 32081547394)
```

Comment: This just satisfies the answers I'm looking for. However suppose we used a number like 78 instead of 51 and y was between say 10^20 and 10^30, would pari gp return the desired values? because I run my problem on PyCharm for instance on my PC and it returns nothing yet, especially with very large ranges.

Comment: @A.J., the heavier the elliptic curve, the more difficult it is to search for integer points on it.

Comment: I get it very clearly, but do you estimate that despite the difficulty, one would still arrive at valid answers or an advanced computer would have to be used? Also, suppose I wanted to solve this problem for a number other than 51, Is there a general way of applying your procedure to solving them? Or what are the changes I could make in your code to solve numbers other than 51?

Comment: @A.J., this code solves specifically your system of equations, which has successfully reduced to an elliptic equation. Any other system of equations will require separate study and, if solved successfully, the construction of another code.